# Save panes layout generated by Origami in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, origami

Thanks to this great plugin : [Origami](https://github.com/SublimeText/Origami)

I am able to obtain the following layout :

[image]

**How could I save this view to call it from the view/layout menu ?**

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the layout data from the `Auto Save Session.sublime-session` file, under the `"layout":` key. This file is in standard JSON format, and can be opened in ST2 just fine (select `View->Syntax->JavaScript->JSON` for syntax highlighting if you want). For OSX, this file is (probably, I'm not in front of my Mac at the moment to verify) located in `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Settings` - it should be in the same directory as the `Packages/` folder where plugins etc. are stored.

So, to make a keyboard shortcut, set up your Origami layout, then perhaps move some files around, search for some text, anything to update the `Auto Save Session.sublime-session` file. It may already have updated after changing your layout, so check the time stamp to make sure. Then, open the file and search for `layout`. Copy the *contents* of the key - the `"cells":`, `"cols":` and `"rows":` keys inside the curly braces, as well as the curly braces themselves. Then, open `Sublime Text 2->Preferences->Key Bindings-User` and add the following to it (include the square brackets if you don't have anything in this file yet, omit them if you already do. If you already do, make sure to add a comma `,` after the last curly brace of the item before):

```json
[
    {
        "keys": ["alt+shift+o"],
        "command": "set_layout",
        "args":
            |
    }
]
```

Set your cursor where I put the `|` character after `"args":` (make sure you delete the `|`) and paste in the contents of the `"layout":` key from `Auto Save Session.sublime-session` you copied earlier. Save the file, and you should now have a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> (O for Origami) that will restore your layout for you. If you have more than one layout you'd like to save, repeat the steps above, and just change the `"keys":` value to another key combination. If you have a lot of plugins, I highly recommend [@skuroda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1852931/skuroda)'s [`FindKeyConflicts`](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) plugin, which is available through [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control) under the same name. With it you can get a full list of all current key mappings, so if you're planning on assigning a new one you can check to see if it's already taken. The plugin does more, as well, so if you're a plugin dev, or just a customization/macro geek like me, it's really quite useful.

As a caveat, with the complexity of the layout you displayed above, the `"layout":` key is going to be quite large and complex, and is made larger by the fact that each value in the `"cells":`, `"cols":` and `"rows":` keys is on its own line. I don't know enough regex to clean everything up automatically, but I'm sure it can be done.

Comment: Will try later tonight, but thank you for your detailed answer !

Comment: No problem. There's all sorts of fun stuff hidden in the `.sublime-session` files just waiting to be exploited.

Comment: @500 - I just realized I didn't tell you how to include your custom layout(s) in the `View->Layout` menu. Do you want me to update the answer? It's actually not that difficult...

Comment: @MattDMo Including it in the `View-Layout` would be helpful. Would be great if you could add this to the answer!